# Map data value come from the websocket into table row

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi guys I am learning Websocket use using saga in react redux. During that time I am passing api in saga and try to get value in my page.
Here the problem is that the value is coming from saga and also print on screen but I cannot able to map that and print the particular data from that api data

Here is my Page where i am calling my data.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { open, close, message } from '../action/action';
import { STATE_ONCLOSE, STATE_ONOPEN, STATE_ONERROR, STATE_ONMESSAGE } from '../reducer/reducer'
import { Button, Table } from 'reactstrap'

const wsid = 'wsid';

class WebSoketEcho extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            messagearea: '',
            addressarea: '',
            value: [],

        };
    }
    sendHandle() {
        this.props.dispatch(message(wsid, this.state.messagearea));
        this.setState({ messagearea: '' });
    }
    closeHandle() {
        this.props.dispatch(close(wsid, false, { code: 1000, reason: 'text' }));
    }
    openHandle() {
        this.props.dispatch(close(wsid));
        this.props.dispatch(open(wsid, this.state.addressarea));

    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.closeHandle();
    }

    render() {
        let ws = this.props.websocket;
        let ls = [];
        ls = this.props.websocket;
        console.log("ls data", ls)
        console.log("Render Data", ws);
        const { state = '', event = null } = ws[wsid] ? ws[wsid] : {};
        let viewValue = [];
        console.log("Get DATAAAA", state);
        switch (state) {
            case STATE_ONOPEN:
            case STATE_ONERROR:
                break;
            case STATE_ONMESSAGE:
                viewValue = event.data;
                    // this.setState({[this.state.value]:event.data})
                break;
            case STATE_ONCLOSE:
                viewValue = event.code + ":" + event.reason;
            //   this.setState({[this.state.value]:event.code+":"+event.reson});
            // this.state.value=event.code+":"+event.reson    
            break;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <p>state:{state}</p>
                <p>value:{viewValue
                    }</p>
                <Table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Pair</td>
                            <td>Amount</td>
                            <td>Price</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {console.log("State", this.props.websocket)}

                        {/* {this.data.map((detais,index)=>{
                            <tr>
                                <td key={index}>{detais.p}</td>
                            </tr>
                        })}         */}
                   
                        <tr>
                            <td >{viewValue}</td>
                            <td >{viewValue}</td>
                            <td >{viewValue}</td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </Table>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.openHandle()}>Open</button>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.closeHandle()}>Close</button><br />
                {/* <input type="text" value={this.state.addressarea} onChange={(e)=>this.setState({addressarea:e.target.value})} placeholder="input address" /><br/>
        <textarea name="messagearea" value={this.state.messagearea} onChange={(e) => this.setState({messagearea: e.target.value})} placeholder="input your text"></textarea>
        <button type="button" onClick={()=>this.sendHandle()}>Send</button> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(websocket) {


    console.log("Map Data:", websocket);
    return websocket ;

}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        dispatch
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WebSoketEcho);
```

My Action File is here

```js
import { createAction } from 'redux-act';
const WSHEADER = '@@redux-saga-websocket-';

export const OPEN = WSHEADER + 'open';
export const MESSAGE = WSHEADER + 'message';
export const CLOSE = WSHEADER + 'close';
export const REMOVE = WSHEADER + 'remove';
export const ONOPEN = WSHEADER + 'onopen';
export const ONMESSAGE = WSHEADER + 'onmessage';
export const ONCLOSE = WSHEADER + 'onclose';
export const ONERROR = WSHEADER + 'onerror';

export const open = createAction(OPEN, (id, url, option) => ({ id, url, option }));
export const message = createAction(MESSAGE, (id, data, option) => ({ id, data, option }));
export const close = createAction(CLOSE, (id, removal, option) => ({ id, removal, option }));
export const remove = createAction(REMOVE, (id) => ({ id }));
export const onopen = createAction(ONOPEN, (id, event) => ({ id, event }));
export const onmessage = createAction(ONMESSAGE, (id, event) => ({ id, event }));
export const onclose = createAction(ONCLOSE, (id, event) => ({ id, event }));
export const onerror = createAction(ONERROR, (id, event) => ({ id, event }));
```

The reducer is look like this

```js
import { createReducer } from 'redux-act';
import { onopen, onclose, onmessage, onerror, remove } from '../action/action';

export const STATE_UNINITIALIZED = 'uninitialized';
export const STATE_ONOPEN = 'onopen';
export const STATE_ONCLOSE = 'onclose';
export const STATE_ONMESSAGE = 'onmessage';
export const STATE_ONERROR = 'onerror';


export const initialState = {
    websocket: {}
};


function updateStateCreator(eventType) {
    return (state, payload ) => {
        const update = {};
        update.websocket = {};
        update.websocket[payload.id] = {
            state: eventType,
            event: payload.event
        };
        return Object.assign({}, state, update);
    }
}
export default createReducer({
    [onopen]: updateStateCreator(STATE_ONOPEN),
    [onclose]: updateStateCreator(STATE_ONCLOSE),
    [onmessage]: updateStateCreator(STATE_ONMESSAGE),
    [onerror]: updateStateCreator(STATE_ONERROR),
    [remove]: (state, payload) => {
        const update = Object.assign({}, state);
        delete update.websocket[payload.id];
        return update;
    }
}, initialState);
```

And Saga File is here

```js
import { eventChannel,END} from 'redux-saga';
import { fork, take, call, put, cancel,takeEvery} from "redux-saga/effects";
import {onopen,onmessage,onclose,onerror,open,message,close} from "../action/action";
/**
 * https://github.com/kuy/redux-saga-chat-example/blob/master/src/client/sagas.js
 */

const sockets={};
function getSocket(id){
 return sockets[id];
}
function setSocket(id,socket){
 sockets[id]=socket;
}
function deleteSocket(id){
 delete sockets[id];
}
/**
 * [connect description]
 * @param  {string} url    url
 * @param  {Object} option protocol,binaryType
 * @return {WebSocket} socket 
 */
function connect(id,option={}){
 if(!getSocket(id)){
   const socket=new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@aggTrade",option.protocol);
   socket.binaryType=option.binaryType?option.binaryType:socket.binaryType;
   setSocket(id,socket);
   return socket;
 }
 return null;
}
function* read(socket,id){
 const channel = yield call(subscribe, socket,id);
 while(true){
  const action=yield take(channel);
  yield put(action);
 }
 //yield takeEvery(channel,put); 
 //This is not supported by redux-saga-test-plan 3.5.0. If redux-saga-test-plan will support this in the future, It can use this.
}

/**
 * 
 * @param  {WebSocket} socket [description]
 * @return {[type]}        [description]
 */
function subscribe(socket,id){
 return eventChannel(emitter=>{
  socket.addEventListener('open',event=>{
   emitter(onopen(id,event));
  });
  socket.addEventListener('error',event=>{
   emitter(onerror(id,event));
  });
  socket.addEventListener('close',event=>{
   emitter(onclose(id,event));
   emitter(END);
   deleteSocket(id);
  });
  socket.addEventListener('message',event=>{
   emitter(onmessage(id,event));
  });
  return ()=>{};
 });
}

function* messageWatcher(){
  yield takeEvery(`${message}`,messageWorker);
}

function* messageWorker(action){
 const {id,data,option={}}=action.payload;
 const socket=yield call(getSocket,id);
 if(socket){
   socket.binaryType=option.binaryType?option.binaryType:socket.binaryType;
   yield call(socket.send.bind(socket),data);
 }
}
function* closeWatcher(){
 yield takeEvery(`${close}`,closeWorker);
}
function* closeWorker(action){
 const {id,removal,option={}}=action.payload;
 const socket=yield call(getSocket,id);
 if(socket){
  yield call(socket.close.bind(socket),option.code,option.reason);
  yield call(deleteSocket,id);
  // if(removal){
  //  yield put(remove,id);
  // }
 }
}
function* openWatcher(){
 yield takeEvery(`${open}`,openWorker);
}
function* openWorker(action){
 const {id,url,option={}}=action.payload;
 const socket=yield call(connect,id,url,option);
 if(socket){
  yield fork(read,socket,id);
 }
}
export default function* wsStart(){
 yield fork(openWatcher);
 yield fork(closeWatcher);
 yield fork(messageWatcher);
}
```

Here I am also share the link from where I am  take the example.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/tignear/websocket-for-redux-saga)

Comment: how's your data look like and what does it mean not able to print? Do you want to know how to iterate it from response?

Comment: Data Is look like this value:{"e":"aggTrade","E":1548056308265,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":86694844,"p":"3523.61000000","q":"0.06007300","f":95981954,"l":95981954,"T":1548056308262,"m":true,"M":true}

Comment: I am not able to print particular parameter like  s , p, q value  from that data

Comment: yes because your data look like object and you treat like an array, did you try with Object.keys ?

Comment: Ok let me try . I am not use object key so thanks for suggestion .

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Object.keys` to iterate the object like

```
 Object.keys(data).map(item=>{
            return(
                <li>{ "Key :"+item +" Value:  " +data[item]}</li>
            )
        })
```

Working Demo [Demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ArsBqTT2qkTZsxfU?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1)

Comment: The solution is good but the data is coming totally unstructured . Not like as need means print  single character at time . Like Value: e Value: : Value: T. I starting getting data but issue is change now

Comment: And Yes When I going to get value with particular  tag means need P tag data then its come undefined